# Sitecore Fallback Dictionary Not Fallback

Tags: sxa, dictionary

In Dictionary Domain folder for a SXA site, there is a field called "Fallback Domain".

I have set that value to Shared site's Dictionary from SXA sites.

But when the site doesn't have a dictionary item defined, its not fallback to Shared site's dictionary item.

Is my expectation of this "Fallback Domain" field setup is correct OR does that field have a different purpose ?